# Copying a feature from a shapefile to another while updating a field

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr

I have two shapefiles.
After iterating on all features of one of them, the code reads a particular field value:

```
 from osgeo import ogr
 driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
 SHP_F = myshaoefilefile1.shp
 SHP_CL = myshapefile2.shp

 SHP_F_DataSource = driver.Open(SHP_F, 1)
 SHP_CL_DataSource = driver.Open(SHP_CL, 1)
 # get the shapefiles layer
 SHP_F_layer = SHP_F_DataSource.GetLayer()
 SHP_CL_layer = SHP_CL_DataSource.GetLayer()
 # estraction of features from  layers
 SHP_F_featureCount = SHP_F_layer.GetFeatureCount()
 SHP_CL_featureCount = SHP_CL_layer.GetFeatureCount()
 for i in range (0, SHP_F_featureCount ):
    for j in range (0, SHP_CL_featureCount ):
          if SHP_CL_layer.GetFeature(j).GetField(4) in ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
             # copy the feature from Layer2 to Layer1 ??
          if SHP_CL_layer.GetFeature(j).GetField(4) in ['string4', 'string5', 'string6']
            # update some field of the inLayer1.GetFeature(i) ??
```

If the field value is equal to a pre-defined string, I need to copy that feature to the first shapefile.
Also I need to update some fields, both integer and string type.
Is there a simple way to copy features from a shapefile to another? The two shapefiles have the same geometry type and the same projection and reference system (WGS84 UTM 33N).
The code is part of a batch python script (python 2.7 version).

Comment: Please  **edit** the question to specify the exact version of GIS software in use. Your code sample is too brief.  Please include enough code to make reproduction possible. You should also specify the coordinate system(s) of the input data.